# The argument type 'Container Function(BuildContext, int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, int, int)'

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling

I try to use `CarousellSlider.builder`, but I get an error. I used the code from the example on the pub.dev page (https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider). I get the error on the line (`itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int itemIndex) => Container(`).

The error message is: `The argument type 'Container Function(BuildContext, int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, int, int)'.`

This is my code:

```
CarouselSlider.builder(
  itemCount: motivationImages.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
       Container();
    }
    options: CarouselOptions(
      height: 300,
    ),
),
```

Comment: Can you share full code of CarouselSlider

Comment: Sorry, i forgot. I've added it now!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like you need an extra `int` parameter. You can use '_' if you don't need to use it.

Comment: what is the purpose of that integer?

Answer (score 6):

use **(BuildContext context, int index, _)**